# xtrachart scrollbar not working into the xtrareport print preview

Tags: winforms, devexpress, xtrareport

I have developed the xtrareport in win-form.NET. In this, i have draw the xtracharts on to the xtrareport .  in this scroll bar not active . & i want to show the date & time in the as difference of the second.I have design the reports & then show into the print preview.
what is the procedure to create the charts in to the xtrareport ?

Comment: Give more detail (i.e you code) for getting help more faster!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't enable chart scrollbars in your report because it's just a generated image.

But you will be able to make your chart clickable and show a real 'live' chart in another dialog. And this chart's scroll bars can be enabled.

Please, review the question at [Q131550](http://www.devexpress.com/issue=Q131550). It describes a problem similar to yours and it has been already solved.